# What is the difference between the two parameters "latest" and "earliest" in web3.eth.getBlock()

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, web3js, cryptocurrency

I would like to know the difference between `"latest"` and `"earliest"` parameters in `web3.eth.getBlock()`, I couldn't find any explanation in the documentation.

**My thoughts**

**Earliest**
Passing `"earliest"` gives you the last available block on or before the code is executed.

**Latest**
Passing "lastest" only returns a new block after the code has been executed.

Please if anyone has information or documentation about this, kindly respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [getBlock()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#getblock) docs point to the [defaultBlock](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#id14) for information about the values.

> "earliest" - String: The genesis block
>
> "latest" - String: The latest block (current head of the blockchain)
>
> "pending" - String: The currently mined block (including pending transactions)

So "latest" is the **newest** block. "Earliest" on the other hand, is the **oldest** block.

Comment: Thanks. My follow up question is, am I going to get whatever block is on top, or it would wait for the next block and return it as latest? The reason for this question is that I want to get the very latest block after the code is run, not whatever is on top as at when the code is run.

Comment: When you execute `web3.eth.getBlock("latest")`, it returns the current latest mined block (e.g. block #100), and doesn't wait for a new block to be mined... If you run it again when there's a new block (e.g. #101), then it returns the block #101 as "latest".

Comment: I added a follow up question below so I can format it properly.

Comment: You can use a WSS provider (instead of a HTTP provider, usually passed in the `new Web3()` constructor) and then [subscribe](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-subscribe.html) to the "newBlockHeaders" WSS messages. This will send you a message each time when there's a new block, and you can use the provided `block.number` (from the message) to request the specific block (or simply the "latest")... A workaround with a HTTP provider would be to poll the `web3.eth.getBlock("latest")` (e.g. each second using `setTimeout()`) but that might hit the rate limits of your provider.

Comment: Great solution Petr. Thank you.

Comment: @PetrHejda How can I get the timestamp of the latest block in with ethers.js please ?

Comment: @DavidJay Ethers.js uses the latest block as default. So you can pass 0 params to the `getBlock()` method and then read its `timestamp` property: `const latestBlockTimestamp = (await provider.getBlock()).timestamp;`